# Cannot Scan QR Code Using Android Studio and Zxing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Hey so I am very new to Android Studio and am sturggling to debug this issue. I want to create a simple QR Code scanner and I am following the tutorial listed in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asl1mFtkMkc&ab_channel=PhilippLackner.
Although, while the code runs it is not picking up the QR code that I give it. The QR code has the text 'hello' in it.

[This is what the tablet sees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9dxU.jpg)

I have tried to debug the issue using the debugger and it seems that when
`decode(binaryBmp)`
is run it throws an error and fails to collect any QR code data. I have also tried with the camera app and it can read the text. I have attached the code below in hopes that someone has any idea why this might be happening.

**Additional Info**
Device- Galaxy Tab A7 Lite
Android Version- 13

**QrCodeAnalyzer.kt**

```
package com.plcoding.qrcodescannercompose

import android.graphics.ImageFormat
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import com.google.zxing.*
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

class QrCodeAnalyzer(
    private val onQrCodeScanned: (String) -> Unit
): ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private val supportedImageFormats = listOf(
        ImageFormat.YUV_420_888,
        ImageFormat.YUV_422_888,
        ImageFormat.YUV_444_888,
    )

    override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
        if(image.format in supportedImageFormats) {
            val bytes = image.planes.first().buffer.toByteArray()
            val source = PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(
                bytes,
                image.width,
                image.height,
                0,
                0,
                image.width,
                image.height,
                false
            )
            val binaryBmp = BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source))
            try {
                val result = MultiFormatReader().apply {
                    setHints(
                        mapOf(
                            DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS to arrayListOf(
                                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
                            )
                        )
                    )
                }.decode(binaryBmp)
                onQrCodeScanned(result.text)
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                image.close()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
        rewind()
        return ByteArray(remaining()).also {
            get(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Edit here is the **MainActivity.kt**

````
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Size
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.camera.core.Camera
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.plcoding.qrcodescannercompose.ui.theme.QrCodeScannerComposeTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            QrCodeScannerComposeTheme {
                var code by remember {
                    mutableStateOf("Lol")
                }
                val context = LocalContext.current
                val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
                val cameraProviderFuture = remember {
                    ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context)
                }
                var hasCamPermission by remember {
                    mutableStateOf(
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            context,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    )
                }
                val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                    contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
                    onResult = { granted ->
                        hasCamPermission = granted
                    }
                )
                LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
                    launcher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                }
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    if (hasCamPermission) {
                        AndroidView(
                            factory = { context ->
                                val previewView = PreviewView(context)
                                val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
                                val selector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                                    .build()
                                preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                                val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                                    .setTargetResolution(
                                        Size(
                                            previewView.width,
                                            previewView.height
                                        )
                                    )
                                    .setBackpressureStrategy(STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                                    .build()
                                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(
                                    ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
                                    QrCodeAnalyzer { result ->
                                        code = result
                                    }
                                )
                                try {
                                    cameraProviderFuture.get().bindToLifecycle(
                                        lifecycleOwner,
                                        selector,
                                        preview,
                                        imageAnalysis
                                    )
                                } catch (e: Exception) {
                                    e.printStackTrace()
                                }
                                previewView
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = code,
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(32.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: What is the error that is thrown in `decode(binaryBmp)`?

Comment: You are probably getting `com.google.zxing.NotFoundException`?   

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10583622/12724973.

You are setting the Preview size as the resolution in ImageAnalysis, so the images you are passing to Zxing will be around Preview size which might be too big for Zxing in Android.

Comment: @TahsinMasrur I created a new variable called `binaryBMPCrop` using the BinaryBitmap crop function and I still get the `com.google.zxing.NotFoundException`.